# MySQL: Counting gold, silver and bronze medals for a player

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have this table:

```
id  game  points  player
---|-----|-------|--------
1  | 1   | 6     | John   
2  | 1   | 5     | Adam
3  | 1   | 7     | Brian
4  | 1   | 8     | Alan
5  | 2   | 6     | John   
6  | 2   | 2     | Adam
7  | 2   | 4     | Brian
8  | 2   | 3     | Alan
```

I am trying to write a query that counts how many gold, silver and bronze medals a person have won.

The result for Alan should be: ( [gold] = 1, [silver] = 0, [bronze] = 1 )

Brian should be: ( [gold] = 0, [silver] = 2, [bronze] = 0 )

I have been able to count the gold medals like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS gold
FROM (`myTable` AS t)
WHERE `t`.`player` = 'Alan'
AND `t`.points = (
    SELECT MAX(`points`)
    FROM `myTable` as tsub
    WHERE `tsub`.`game` = `t`.`game`
)
```

The silver and bronze medals seems to be a lot more difficult.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT:
To clarify how the medals are awarded.

Gold: Goes to the player(s) with the highest score in the game.

Silver: Goes to the player(s) with the second highest score in the game.

Bronze: Goes to the player(s) with the third highest score in the game.

Mulitple games are stored in the table.

If two players have been awarded gold, no silver medal will be awarded.
The two highest scores were a tie so the next best score will be the third highest score and will therefore be awarded the bronze medal.

Comment: how many points for each gold, silver and bronze?

Comment: What happens when there is a tie?

Comment: If the person has the highest score in the game, he gets the gold medal. Second highest score = silver and so forth.

About the tie: If two players share the highest score, they both get a gold medal and the player with the third highest score should get a bronze medal.

Answer (score 0):

This will be helpful

update your medal criteria if required

```
select 
name, 
(SELECT count(*) FROM myTable g where g.points > 5 and g.name=myTable.name) as gold,
(SELECT count(*) FROM myTable g where g.points > 2 and g.points <= 5 and g.name=myTable.name) as silver,
(SELECT count(*) FROM myTable g where g.points <= 2 and g.name=myTable.name) as gold
from myTable
group by name
```

Comment: This wont help much I'm afraid. I have edited my question to clarify how medals should be awarded.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example...

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

 CREATE TABLE my_table 
 (game INT NOT NULL
 ,points INT NOT NULL
 ,player VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
 ,PRIMARY KEY(game,player)
 );

 INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
 (1,6,'John'),
 (1,5,'Adam'),
 (1,7,'Brian'),
 (1,8,'Alan'),
 (2,6,'John'),
 (2,2,'Adam'),
 (2,4,'Brian'),
 (2,3,'Alan');

 SELECT player
      , SUM(rank=1) gold
      , SUM(rank=2) silver
      , SUM(rank=3) bronze 
   FROM
      (
        SELECT x.*
             , COUNT(*) rank 
          FROM my_table x 
          JOIN my_table y 
            ON y.game = x.game 
           AND y.points >= x.points 
         GROUP 
            BY game
             , player
      ) a
  GROUP 
     BY player;
 +--------+------+--------+--------+
 | player | gold | silver | bronze |
 +--------+------+--------+--------+
 | Adam   |    0 |      0 |      0 |
 | Alan   |    1 |      0 |      1 |
 | Brian  |    0 |      2 |      0 |
 | John   |    1 |      0 |      1 |
 +--------+------+--------+--------+
```